# custom tab limit got exceeded ,how can i use it

Tags: custom-object, custom

My Org Uses EE ,the custom tab limit got exceeded .I have created a custom object where im unable to see it,Is there any possibility where i can access the custom object.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One option would be to query for one record and viewing the ID of the record. The first three characters of the ID identify the object type, and putting them in the url will lead you to the page of that object, for instance: na1.salesforce.com/a01, in which case a01 are the first three characters of the ID.

Comment: @Lex:Thanks for your reply.But i have not yet created any record

Comment: You could use the developer console to create one maybe? Or use the describe-functions to get the 3 character code.

Comment: @Lex:I tried in DC executing a few lime code as :OpportunityLineItem__c Oli = new OpportunityLineItem__c(); Oli.PricingRequestsQuarterNos__c ='2Q15'; Oli.ProductPartNumbers__c ='BXRC-25E4000-F-04'; system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+'Oli'); insert Oli; But could not get the record id in my debug log.What is the Describe function ??Can u brief me about it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

@Nikkey 
Two options for you.
Option 1: Log a case to support to increase your tab limit.
Option 2: Create Custom Links on Home Page by getting the KeyPrefix of Object using Apex as suggested by @Lex.